# How to build seperate Apk's for multiple arhitecture in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, armv7

I am trying to build multiple apk's but the Google Play Games plugin uses libraries for both architectures. The apk file size has been reduced but contains libgpg.so for x86 as well armv7.

I tried available solutions but none of them worked. I tried deleting libgpg.so for one architecture from project folder but when I compile libgpg.so comes back again.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the solution. Every time after changing build architecture I have to force re solve dependencies to make it work. I have auto resolution dependencies turned off.